# Remove back button from header in React Native and React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Tried these two ways, but none worked:

```
options={{
  headerLeft: () => {
     return null}
}}

// method 2
screenOptions={{
   headerLeft: null,
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it for all screens or for one of them like so:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
  // For all screens inside this Stack Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerBackVisible: false,
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    // For the login screen inside this Stack Navigator
    options={{ headerBackVisible: false }}
    component={LoginScreen}
    name="Login"
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```